# android layout weight and gravity issues

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to get a better understanding of android layouts. In the following example I solved my problem but only through trial and error. I would like to understand WHY it worked.

I am setting up a "header" line inside another layout. I want the first part to use as much of the width as possible and the second part to use only what it needs. So I set layout_1 to have a weight of 1, layout_2 to have a weight of 0. Originally, I had both with layout_width of match_parent. That caused layout_2 to take the entire width and made layout_1 disappear. I finally fixed it by setting width on layout_2 to wrap_content. I understand that it makes sense for layout_2 to have width wrap_content. But don't understand why layout_2 match_parent would take the entire width when it has weight of 0 and layout_1 also has width match_parent.

An example of the code follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_width="match_parent">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header_layout_1"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_gravity="center"   >

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="some text"/>
    </LinearLayout>

   <!-- changing width on header_layout_2 to match_parent takes over layout, wrap_content gives me what I want -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header_layout_2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="0">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="some more text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<!--end of header-->
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find lots of sources and blogs on The Internet about **LinearLayout** and **layout_weight**.

There are some useful websites:

https://ugia.io/2012/01/19/android-linearlayout-distribution-explained-weight-and-sizes/

http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-android-s-layout-weight-attribute.html

https://blog.stylingandroid.com/layout-weights-part-1/

https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-linearlayout-example/